# How do I prove that these two numbers are the only eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space.
Let $W$ be a proper nonzero subspace of $V$, and let $P : V → V$ be the orthogonal projection onto $W$.

How do I prove that the only eigenvalues of $P$ are $0$ and $1$?

My "proof":
Since P is an orthogonal projection, this means that the kernel of P = 0. Therefore, 0 is an eigenvalue because by definition, an eigenvalue is a scalar that extends a vector - and 0 extends the vector that is orthogonal. 1 is the only other eigenvalue because it is the eigenvalue of the vector parallel to the projection.

Is that a sufficient "proof?" I'm kinda lost here.

Answer (score 3):

$V = U \oplus W$. For each $v \in V$, we have $P(v) = P(u + w) = w$ and $P^{2}(v) = P(w) = w = P(v)$. Hence, $P^{2} = P$.

Now, suppose $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $P$, then there exists a nonzero vector $v$ such that $(\lambda - \lambda^{2})v = \lambda v - \lambda^{2}v = Pv - P^{2}v = 0 \implies \lambda(1- \lambda) =0$. Hence $\text{Spec}(P) = \{0, 1 \}$.

Answer (score 1):

Take an orthonormal basis $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_k$ for the proper subspace $W.$ Extend it to an orthonormal basis for $V$ as   $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_k, v_{k+1}, \ldots, v_n.$ What does the mapping $P$ do to $v_{k+1},$ for example?

Answer (score 1):

Any projection $P$ satisfies $P^2 = P$, i.e. $P^2 - P = 0$.  If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for eigenvector $x$, that means 
$0 = P^2 x - P x = (\lambda^2 - \lambda) x$, so $\lambda^2 - \lambda = 0$.  Thus the only possible eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$, the roots of the polynomial $\lambda^2 - \lambda$.  And these are indeed eigenvalues: an eigenvector for eigenvalue $1$ is any nonzero member of $W$, and an eigenvector for $0$ is any vector that projects to $0$.